# replacingOccurrences throws an error by using an array for options

Tags: swift, swift5

Can someone explain me the difference between the following code snippets?
I do not understand why the second one throws an error.

This one works:

```
"Anno 1800".replacingOccurrences(of: "N", with: "#", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive], range: nil)
```

But this one gives an error:

```
let optionsArr = [NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive]
"Anno 1800".replacingOccurrences(of: "N", with: "#", options: optionsArr, range: nil)
```

> error: StringExtensions.playground:110:63: error: cannot convert value of type '[NSString.CompareOptions]' to expected argument type 'String.CompareOptions' (aka 'NSString.CompareOptions')
>     "Anno 1800".replacingOccurrences(of: "N", with: "#", options: optionsArr, range: nil)

Answer (score 4):

Please read the error message carefully.

> cannot convert value of **array** *something* to expected argument type **non-array** *something*.

Well, the syntax of an **OptionSet** and an **array** is quite similar, we got comma separated items wrapped in square brackets.

Unfortunately they are different. To specify an OptionSet literally you have to annotate the type to avoid ambiguity.

```
let optionsArr : String.CompareOptions = [NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive]
"Anno 1800".replacingOccurrences(of: "N", with: "#", options: optionsArr, range: nil)
```

After specifying the type you can write the expression *swiftier*

```
let optionsArr : String.CompareOptions = [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]
```

The first version works because the compiler is clever enough to infer the type

Comment: Hey vadian, thx for your answer. 
Just to clarify. Yes i have read the error message carefully and the difference between an array and an non array type is absolutly clear for me. But i was confused about the working code and the error message as well. I have overlooked the OptionSet type and i didn't know them as well. For a beginner in swift it is not easy to understand all the details. So thanks for clarification. I will have a deeper look at OptionSet to understand that in detail.